# Function template specialization in MacOSX with clang

Tags: c++, templates

I am porting some codes from Windows to MacOSX. There is a problem about Function template specialization.
**I was successfully compile this file in Windows with msvc14.0 and clang5.0.**

```
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

#include <iostream>

template<typename CHAR_TYPE>
size_t string_length(CHAR_TYPE text)
{
    static_assert(false, "string_length is not supported this type.");
    return 0;
}

template<typename CHAR_TYPE>
size_t string_length(const std::basic_string<CHAR_TYPE>& text)
{
    return text.size();
}

template<>
inline size_t string_length(const char* szText)
{
    return strlen(szText);
}

template<>
inline size_t string_length(const wchar_t* szwText)
{
    return wcslen(szwText);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "SZ length " << string_length("IIII") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "WSZ length " << string_length(L"IIII") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "string length " << string_length(std::string("IIII")) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "wstring length " << string_length(std::wstring(L"IIII")) << std::endl;
}
```

When I compile it in MacOSX with clang5.0, I got a error:

```
clang_test.cpp:9:5: error: static_assert failed "string_length is not supported
      this type."
    static_assert(false, "string_length is not supported this type.");
    ^             ~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

When I Remove the first function:

```
template<typename CHAR_TYPE>
size_t string_length(CHAR_TYPE text)
{
    static_assert(false, "string_length is not supported this type.");
    return 0;
}
```

I got some other errors:

```
clang_test.cpp:19:15: error: no function template matches function template
      specialization 'string_length'
inline size_t string_length(const char* szText)
              ^
clang_test.cpp:13:8: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'const
      basic_string<type-parameter-0-0, char_traits<type-parameter-0-0>,
      allocator<type-parameter-0-0> > &' against 'const char *'
size_t string_length(const std::basic_string<CHAR_TYPE>& text)
       ^
clang_test.cpp:25:15: error: no function template matches function template
      specialization 'string_length'
inline size_t string_length(const wchar_t* szwText)
              ^
clang_test.cpp:13:8: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'const
      basic_string<type-parameter-0-0, char_traits<type-parameter-0-0>,
      allocator<type-parameter-0-0> > &' against 'const wchar_t *'
size_t string_length(const std::basic_string<CHAR_TYPE>& text)
       ^
clang_test.cpp:33:34: error: no matching function for call to 'string_length'
    std::cout << "SZ length " << string_length("IIII") << std::endl;
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
clang_test.cpp:13:8: note: candidate template ignored: could not match
      'basic_string<type-parameter-0-0, char_traits<type-parameter-0-0>,
      allocator<type-parameter-0-0> >' against 'char const[5]'
size_t string_length(const std::basic_string<CHAR_TYPE>& text)
       ^
clang_test.cpp:34:35: error: no matching function for call to 'string_length'
    std::cout << "WSZ length " << string_length(L"IIII") << std::endl;
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
clang_test.cpp:13:8: note: candidate template ignored: could not match
      'basic_string<type-parameter-0-0, char_traits<type-parameter-0-0>,
      allocator<type-parameter-0-0> >' against 'wchar_t const[5]'
size_t string_length(const std::basic_string<CHAR_TYPE>& text)
       ^
4 errors generated.
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is indeed wrong even if function is not instantiated:

```
template<typename CHAR_TYPE>
size_t string_length(CHAR_TYPE text)
{
    static_assert(false, "string_length is not supported this type.");
    return 0;
}
```

[temp.res/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.res#8):

> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> - If no valid specialization can be generated for a template definition, and that template is not instantiated, the template deﬁnition is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.
> - [..]
> - a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter, or
> - [..]

You may use instead (and use overload instead of specialization for `const char*`, `const wchar_t*`):

```
template<typename CHAR_TYPE>
size_t string_length(CHAR_TYPE text) = delete;
```

If you prefer to keep the `static_assert`, you have to create an helper:

```
template <typename T> struct always_false : false_type {};

template<typename CHAR_TYPE>
size_t string_length(CHAR_TYPE text)
{
    static_assert(always_false<CHAR_TYPE>::value,
                  "string_length is not supported this type.");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's *the* bullet that applies. But yeah, [temp.res]/8 for 90% of illegal template definitions.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Edited to include your bullet too which is indeed more appropriate.